# How to get peer list from gundb server

Tags: sockets, websocket, gun, gundb

I'd like to get peers' data who are connected with gunDB. Although I tried to create and manage my own peer list from [wire](https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/b5fd757db48aaa71e2226814ef4e370688059b3e/lib/wire.js#L70). But I think if gunDB already has the peer list, using it would be better than mine.

So could you please advise how I can get the peer list from the gunDB server?

I checked the peer list [here](https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/master/gun.js#L2132) which creates peer id and pushes peer to **peer list(opt.peers)**. but I have no idea how I call the list from outside like on my server scripts.

Please give me advice about that!

Answer (score 2):

@huhsame I'll have to answer this question in more detail later, but for now just gonna paste some code to get you started:

```
gun.back('opt.peers')
```

or

```
gun._.opt.peers
```

I recommend the API approach rather than the "internal" `_` approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, it would be helpful for my project :)

Answer (score 0):

@marknadal

Sorry I am late because it was a Lunar new year holiday

I tested `gun.back('opt.peers')` **(gun-peers)** as you answered with my peer list **(huh-peers)** which I made using `WebSocket Wire and Mesh.hi in gun`. I found some problems so I'd like to share it with you.

1. result at client
2. result at the server

**1. the result at client**

I tested it on four browser instances - left(chrome), middle(chrome), right(opera), safari(safari) -
[client peer list - start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiHR7.jpg)

- gun-peers prints id by **WebRTC** of each peer including the server - [gun-peers first try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUw22.png). I think it is more useful than huh-peers which is got from the server when the page is served because it can check other peers whom I connected with currently.
- If I refresh some of the clients, gun-peers prints peer list including the previous peer information before refreshing - [refreshing vedio](https://youtu.be/Qc_2dAw2viU). As a result, at the right one which is refreshed last, gun-peers prints right peer list. But at the left and the right one, previous peer information is printed - [after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGHLn.jpg)
- If I connect the same space at [Safari which doesn't work WebRCT](https://github.com/amark/gun/issues/834), gun-peers prints just the server at safari and at others(left, middle and right) prints without the information of safari - [with safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCasD.jpg)

**2. the result at server**

there are some results in **each case in 1. the result at the client.**

- gun-peers prints id by WebSocket unlike at client printing id by WebRTC, and it prints **just N-1 peer**s - [comparison gun-peers and huh-peers at server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsCL4.jpg)
- In the safari case like as I mentioned at 1.4, the number of gun-peers at the server is increased even though it doesn't print at the client side as I mentioned. But gun-peers still prints only N-1 peers as I mentioned 2.1 - [at server with safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7I8d.jpg)

So I decided to use huh-peers temporarily. I am wondering why there is a different result like that. even though huh-peers is based on GunDB connection data.

Please take a look at it. Thank you :)